# Вытащить id записи из RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Передаю в ViewHolder объект, которые включает три значения: id, title и status. Нужно вытащить по нажатию id элемента.
Код адаптера:

```
public class AdapterData extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterData.ViewHolder>{

    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    Context context;

    public AdapterData(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context){
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reports_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(listItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView title, status;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Вы нажали на " + /*Вот здесь нужно получить id элемента*/ + " элемент!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        public void bind(ListItem item){
            title.setText(item.getTitle());
            status.setText(item.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ListItem - это класс какой-то? что в нем лежит?

Comment: Три значения: id, title & status элемента

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить элемент массива можно таким способом:

```
ListItems lisItem = listItems.get(getAdapterPosition())
```

ну и дальше уже это можно использовать в месте обработки клика:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ListItems lisItem = listItems.get(getAdapterPosition())
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Вы нажали на " + /*Вот здесь нужно получить id элемента*/ + " элемент!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
```

так как у вас теперь есть объект класса, то вы можете получить из него все что вам может понадобится для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Да, уже так и реализовал) Спасибо за помощь)